# Appropriate container for storing/keeping chromic acid?

Tags: acid-base, safety

I am planning to make **chromic acid**, however I the information for keeping chromic acid are conflicting. Can it be stored in a glass bottle even though it's used as a glass etchant? Also I saw some information that it's dangerous to keep it in plastic containers. What's the common practice?

Comment: The common practice would be to prepare chromic acid only if strictly necessary, and in an adequate environment (lab, special workshop, ...) and your question doesn't suggest it is the case.

Comment: Plastic is surely no good.

Comment: It's *not* a glass etchant.

Comment: it used to be stored in glass back in the day when I was doing my PhD and was used as a glass cleaner not an etchant

Answer (score 1):

Chromic acid can well be stored in glass bottles with stopper/lid but should be kept away from any organic compounds. Chromic acid is a dangerous oxidising agent and incompatible with various organic compounds. Also, it should be well marked with proper label and hazard symbol to distinguish it from other mineral acids. It has a decent shelf life and can be kept for long period without decomposition if kept well.

Also make sure it remains separated from mineral acid. Chromic acid is known to form solution with sulfuric acid forming **chromosulfuric acid** which is *ironically* used to clean laboratory glasswares.

Chromic acid is not a glass etchant.